# Unable to run batch file

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe

I'm trying to run a .bat file which contains the below code

```
echo "Test"
pause
```

It throws the following error

```
Windows cannot find 'c:\Users\test\Desktop\run.bat'.
Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

[image]

The above user has all administrator rights.

But when I run this .bat as  **Run as Administrator** it is executing properly. I tried running in new user account with admin privileges but still no luck.

I tried to modify regedit:

```
Hkey_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat
```

But .bat key doesn't exist there.

Comment: is your cmd.exe file within the system32 folder?

Comment: What happens if you put the .bat file in another folder, say, c:\temp?

Comment: How are you (trying to) run it? Double-click in Windows Explorer? "Run" dialog box (Win+R)? From an interactive Command Prompt?

Answer (score 1):

check to see if the actual cmd.exe is within the system32 folder, if it is then try opening the file through the cmd itself.

```
C:\Users\kamal\Desktop\run.bat
```