# Unable to doubleclick and run .bat files

Tags: windows, windows-7

There seems to be some issue with my system environment variable. Whenever i double click .bat files i get error message saying the very file i am clicking is not found. But it runs fine when i right click and run as administrator.

The I believe is causing problems while I am trying to install some software. where the installer would fail with error text similar to "Createprocess error=2 while trying to execute C;\aa\bb\xxxxx.bat" but the file always exists.

This link seems to be closely related to the problem but there was no solution posted there.
http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/339706-windows-cant-find-file-when-trying-run-bat-file.html

Could someone help me resolve this strange behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: We can assume you are asking how to fix this, but we could be wrong. It would be very helpful if you included a question.

Comment: "Whenever i double click .bat files i get error message saying the very file i am clicking is not found.". this sounds like you're confusing where the error is coming from. It's most likely not telling you it can't find the batch file you're running, it's a command inside the batch file telling you it can't find a file.  If it's trying to access a file that is in folder in accessible to a standard user, then that's why it works when run "as administrator".

Comment: Also, does EVERY batch file behave this way, or only a specific one?

Comment: I tested with a batch file containing single echo statement and got the same error as well.

So i think every batch file is having the same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to run batch file](http://superuser.com/q/822462/354511), although the "answer" there isn't much of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on it and in the general tab check to unblock it if it was downloaded from the internet. Be sure your AV does not block it too.

Comment: I tried it while blocking AV. and in the general tab it is neither readonly or hidden.